# How do I generate a PDF document from HTML Page WCAG 2.0 AA Accessiblity Compliant?

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation

We have a scenario wherein we need to generate a PDF document WCAG 2.0 AA Accessibility compliant from an HTML page.

We are considering two tools to generate PDFs:

1. Crystal Reports
2. iTextSharp

I have the following queries/concerns:

1. Will the rules be taken care by the PDF generating tools?
2. We do not know if the tool takes care of generating AA compliant PDF if the HTML page is AA compliant. If no, then how can we achieve it? Do we need to configure/customize the tool to achieve the expected result?
3. Is there any other tool we can consider(freeware) to generate it easily?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? you are asking about two tools, did you use either of these and attempt to output tagged PDF? You question shows no attempt at even trying to answer your own question.

Answer (score -1):

I just did something like this last week, I used a tool called FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/)
just download the v1.7 zip. then copy the folder over to your server.

then you will need to include a file, and then write something like this:

require('../include/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,"$id_user");

$pdf->image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=$i",50,50,0,0,"PNG");

$pdf->Output();

and the chart.googleapis is nothing to worry about. I used the $pdf->image to generate a QR code. so you can delete that line, unless you need it.